# How to use variables of a class in T4 CodeGen

Tags: c#

as mentioned in the tilte, I just cant figure out after intense amount of google search, how to use a variable from a class, lets say:

```
public class Candy
{
    public Int Length;  
}
```

in my EnumGen.tt file!

the "EnumGen.tt" looks like:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ parameter name="Length" type="System.Int32" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>


<#    int descrapancy = 20;  #>

namespace Learning2D
{
   public enum CandyDescrapancy
  {
    <#for(int i = 0; i < Length; i++)  //Length shall be the class variable from the CandyClass
    { 
    #>   
     index_<#=i.ToString()#> = <#=descrapancy#>, 
    <#descrapancy+=20;#>
   <#}#> 
 }
```

}

Note: Both files are in the same namespace!

I would be so glad if you could enlighten me in that regard^^

Best regards

Shpend

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that.

Remember that T4 templates are run *at compile time.* They can't reference your variable's value because nothing is actually running that code yet. Your `Candy` class hasn't even been *compiled* at this point, let alone anything setting an actual value into its `Length` field.

The goal of the T4 template is to generate code that will then be compiled alongside your `Candy` class, not use the code in the same assembly to perform actions at runtime.

Comment: Hi Chris, thx for the answer first oif all, but isnt it possibly to get somehow a runtime parametert, i have read of smth along the lines of "runtime text processing" ? would this work, also afaik there is smth called "parameter" tag, where u can define a parameter and call then from your codebase "CallContext.TransformText(..)"?

Comment: Sure, you can invoke the T4 transformer at runtime in your code to transform arbitrary templates, but at that point you are passing the values into the transformation call yourself from your own running code. The template still has no idea that it may have come from the `Candy` class, it just knows that an external source has provided it with a parameter value.

Comment: hi chris, this is fine acrtually, it doenst need the track from where the variable comes from, I add a comment that it comes from the Candy but its not bound to this particular fact. It just needs the data passed in :-) but this could work you say?

Comment: Yeah, that's absolutely a viable way of passing parameters into the template generator. In case you haven't seen it, reading up on the parameter part would be a good intro. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/t4-parameter-directive?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

If you have built your project succesfully (and try to avoid cleaning the project before building) your current project's assembly should be reference-able from your T4 file.

You would need something like this:

```
 <#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)YourProjectAssembly.dll" #>
 <#@ import namespace="YourProjectAssembly.YourNamespace" #>
```

and then you will be able to use you `Candy` class in your T4 file.

```
namespace Learning2D
{
    public enum CandyDescrapancy
    {

    <#
    var candy = new Candy()
    {
        Length = 100;//or whatever
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < candy.Length; i++) 
    { 
#>   
    index_<#=i.ToString()#> = <#=descrapancy#>, 
    <#descrapancy+=20;#>
<#  }#> 
}
```

### Some things to look out for

- This example assumes your project is compiled to a DLL with the name "YourProjectAssembly.dll". This is common for web projects. Might not work for desktop applications which compile to an .exe
- T4 files are run at compile time, meaning that you will be referencing the classes in the last successful build. Not the current one
- If you clean (or rebuild) your project/solution at any point, the T4 may fail to run because cleaning deletes all files in the output folder.

Comment: Hi peter, thanks for ur response, i mean, i do build, but it only creates "myproject.csproj"  I am working in conjunction with unity 2019 latest version and when I do a "build" from VS2019 it doesnt show me a .dll sadly, need to look how to make it happen

Comment: The `TargetPath` is the folder where the project's output goes. Usually the `bin\Debug\` or  `bin\x86\Debug\` folders depending on your project's configuration. The .csproj file you are referring to is the C# project file which is the one visual studio opens when you click "File > Open Project".
Go and check in that folder if you have a dll with the same name as your project.

Comment: i did include it in the assembly definition and it says.

Comment: I get a "UnauthorizedException" when I include that .dll

Comment: <#@ assembly name="C:\Users\shho3\OneDrive\Desktop\TODO\Projekte\PROGRAMMIERPROJEKTE\2D UFO Tutorial Game\Build\2D UFO Tutorial Game_Data\Managed" #> Since im not sure, how unity overwrites the "TargertPath" value, i did it like this

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with how Unity organises files. Your other option would be to add you class in a separate class library project and reference it in your T4 file. Sorry I can't be much help